# Is there a way to search for expired bounties?

Tags: support, bounties, data-explorer

I would like to search for questions that had bounties, but no bounty was awarded. Is this possible by data.stackexchange.com queries or the sorts?

Comment: this is absurd question, if the bounty has expired, then the bounty must have been awarded.

Comment: @Lie http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work "If no answers meet these criteria, the bounty ends without it being awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112274/) works:

```sql
SELECT P.Id AS [Post Link]
FROM Posts AS P, Votes AS V
WHERE P.Id = V.PostId
AND V.VoteTypeId = 8
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Posts, Votes
    WHERE Posts.ParentId = P.ID
    AND Votes.VoteTypeId = 9
);​
```

Comment: Thanks Michael I totally forgot about VoteTypeId I was playing with other stuff.